# Conditional Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a record when the difference between 2 columns, say a and b, is greater than 0.01. I am not proficient in stored procedures or T-SQL, but I want something like

```
if (a - b > 0.01) 
    then update statement
```

What is the correct strategy for going about this?

Comment: When the _difference_ is greater than 0.01 would be `Abs( A - B ) > 0.01`. Or do you just want cases where `A` is larger than `B` by at least 0.01?

Answer (score 0):

If a is a calculated value from columns from multiple tables -

If `a` Column has a relation with the table you are updating then better use tables in  `Join` and Columns in `WHERE` condition.

```
Update t
SET Column = ''
From Table t
Join Table1 t1 on t1.a = t.a
WHERE (t.a - b) > 0.01
```

You can use `IF ELSE` Statement if `a and b` column doesn't have relation with your update table

```
Declare @a int = 1, @b int = 2

IF (@a-@b > 0.01) 
BEGIN
    -- If you have Update statement without condition then it will update all the Column records 
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    Print 'FALSE' 
    -- code block run when condition is FALSE
END
```

Comment: what if a and b are not columns in the same table.. what if a is a calculated value from columns from multiple tables ?